# Rails assets pipeline not including files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have this in my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require prettyprint
//= require_tree .
```

And this is my configuration for production:

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

When I push to Heroku I get:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_6a112dd5-b53f-4798-94d6-22ecc2b1edc4/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_6a112dd5-b53f-4798-94d6-22ecc2b1edc4/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_6a112dd5-b53f-4798-94d6-22ecc2b1edc4/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_6a112dd5-b53f-4798-94d6-22ecc2b1edc4/Rakefile:7)
       Asset precompilation completed (3.37s)
-----> WARNINGS:
       Injecting plugin 'rails_log_stdout'
       Injecting plugin 'rails3_serve_static_assets'
       Add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile to skip plugin injection
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information."
```

But when I go to my application.js in heroku, file is blank.

## Update

Maybe I did not put this is my question, but Heroku needs now:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

in Gemfile. I bundled. Not working yet.

What am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean by "when I go to my application.js in heroku" ?

Comment: when I visit `http://myherokuapp.com/assets/application.js`, note link is not real.

Comment: I see, you might want to read this first, to understand how assets pipeline works http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I will take another read on that, can you give me some more specific pointer?

Comment: I wrote `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in  `config/environments/production.rb`, no results.

Comment: also in `application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

have you precompiled your assets with:
`rake assets:precompile`
 in your cmd prompt before deploying?

Comment: no, I don't need this since Heroku does that in remote server

Comment: no it dosnt... usualy you use tools like capistrano to do it before deploy, if you are not using something like capistrano you should precompile them manualy...

Comment: heroku does, see log I pasted.

Comment: yes, it precompiles fine locally, I suppose I will give it a try, I mean I suppose you mean to push precompiled assets into Heroku, although I don't like this way, neither dislike it, but I would like this to be auto by Heroku.

Comment: its just the way it is... like i told you, you should use a tool like capistrano to make it automatic for you, heroku dosnt like to waste recoursess precompiling your assets for you. if this solved your problem thumb ups and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the following:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

by

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
```

in your `application.rb` file.

It should look like this:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

Comment: Same thing, `application.js` appears empty in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Ruby `1.9.3` in production or upgrade your version of Rails to `3.2.14` or above.

Older versions of Rails do not play well with Ruby 2.0. Specifically sprockets breaks: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/352

In the future you should consider locking down your version of Ruby in your `Gemfile` so you get the exact same experience in development and production. In your Gemfile add:

```
ruby "2.0.0"
```

Comment: I have not tested yet, I hope I have time for this later.